# How to add animation to a group sprite in phaser.js?

Tags: animation, sprite, phaser-framework

How do I animate a sprite that's already been added to a group?

Here's my spritesheet:

```
game.load.spritesheet('enemyBullet', 'assets/games/invaders/enemy-bullet.png', 11, 19);
```

Here's the group:

```
// The enemy's bullets
enemyBullets = game.add.group();
enemyBullets.enableBody = true;
enemyBullets.physicsBodyType = Phaser.Physics.ARCADE;
enemyBullets.createMultiple(30, 'enemyBullet');
enemyBullets.setAll('anchor.x', 0.5);
enemyBullets.setAll('anchor.y', 1);
enemyBullets.setAll('outOfBoundsKill', true);
enemyBullets.setAll('checkWorldBounds', true);
```

Here's the code I think I should add.

```
enemyBullets.animations.add('fly3', [ 0, 1, 2, 3], 20, true);
enemyBullets.play('fly3');
```

However, if I add that anywhere in the above group code block I get the error *'enemyBullets.animations.' undefined'*.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I figured out my answer:

```
enemyBullets.callAll('animations.add', 'animations', 'fly3', [0,1,2,3], 16, true);
enemyBullets.callAll('play', null, 'fly3');
```

Tested and it works.

Comment: so how would you animate a bullet hit?